# Borel Measurability

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

(Borel measurability) A function $f$ is said to be {\bf Borel measurable} provided its domain $E$ is a Borel set and for each $c$, the set $\{x \in E| f(x)>c\}$ is a Borel set. Show that

(i) if $f$ and $g$ are Borel measurable so are $af+bg$ and $fg$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

(ii) every Borel measurable function is Lebesgue measurable.

(ii) if $f$ is Borel measurable and $B$ is a Borel set then $f^{-1}(B)$ is a Borel set.

(iii) if $f$ and $g$ are Borel measurable then $f \circ g$ is Borel measurable.

(iv) if $f$ is Borel measurable and $g$ is Lebesgue measurable then $f \circ g$ is Lebesgue measurable.

*Proofs:*

(i) If $a$ or $b$ is $0$, then this is trivial. If $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, we may write

$$\{x: af+bg(x) > c\} = \bigcup_{\substack{s,r \in \mathbb{Q}^{+} \\ s\leq a, r \leq b }} \bigcup_{\substack{m,n \in \mathbb{Q} \\ m+n \leq c}} \{x: sf(x) > m \} \cap \{x : rg(x) > n \}, $$

which is measurable. Now, the other cases of $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^-$, $a \in \mathbb{R}^+, b \in \mathbb{R}^-$, and $a \in \mathbb{R}^-, b \in \mathbb{R}^+$ are handled similarly.

For $fg$, we may write \begin{align*} \{x : fg(x) > c\} &= 
\left( \bigcup_{\substack{a,b \in \mathbb{Q}^+\\ ab \geq c}} \{x: f(x) > a \} \cap \{x : g(x) > b\} \right) \cup \left( \bigcup_{\substack{a \in \mathbb{Q}^-\\ b \in \mathbb{Q}^+ \\ ab \geq c}} \{x: f(x) < a \} \cap \{x : g(x) > b\} \right)  \\ 
& \cup \left( \bigcup_{\substack{a \in \mathbb{Q}^+\\ b \in \mathbb{Q}^- \\ ab \geq c}} \{x: f(x) > a \} \cap \{x : g(x) < b\} \right) \cup \left( \bigcup_{\substack{a,b \in \mathbb{Q}^-\\ ab \geq c}} \{x: f(x) < a \} \cap \{x : g(x) < b\} \right)
\end{align*}

so $fg$ is measurable.

(ii) Every Borel Measurable set is Lebesgue Measurable, since if $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, then $B$ is the same as a Lebesgue Measurable set except possibly on a set of measure $0$.

(iii) Assuming $f: (X,\mathcal{T}) \to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{U})$ with $(X,\mathcal{T})$ a general topological space, and $\mathcal{U}$ the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$, by definition, any Borel set $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is result of countable set operations on an open set. Now, given $f^{-1}((c,\infty)) \in \mathcal{B}(X)$, any open set may be written in terms of these open rays, and any Borel set in $\mathbb{R}$ may be written in terms of these open sets. Ergo, the inverse image of a Borel Set in $\mathbb{R}$ is the countable set theoretic result of operations on $f^{-1}((c,\infty))$, which is again a Borel Set, since $\mathcal{B}(X)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

(iii) Assume $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Then, $(f \circ g)^{-1} ((c,\infty)) = g^{-1} \circ f^{-1} ((c,\infty))$. By hypothesis, $f^{-1} ((c,\infty)) = B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. By definition of Borel Sets, any member of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the result of countable set operations on a member of the topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Any member of the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ may be written as the countable result of set operations on $(a,\infty)$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$, so $g^{-1} (B) \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, so $f \circ g$ is Borel Measurable.

(iv) I don't see what there is to prove here? Is it not the exact same argument as (iii) with a simple replacement of terminology?

**Are the above proofs correct?** What exactly is the purpose of (iv)?

Comment: About (iv): $f$ Borel-measurable implies that $f$ is Lebesguemeasurable(stated in (ii)). So is $g$ and then also their composition $f\circ g$. You proved this in (iii) for Borel-$\sigma$ algebra, but it is true for *any* $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @drhab Yes yes of course, which is why it seems like a silly question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that you are not this far yet with your study, but I cannot withold myself from sharing this.

The Borelfunctions $f,g:E\rightarrow\mathbb R$ induce a function $h:E\rightarrow\mathbb R^2$ prescribed by $x\mapsto\langle f(x),g(x)\rangle$.

This $h$ is also a Borelfunction in the sense that $h^{-1}(B)\subseteq E$ is a Borelset for any $B$ that belongs to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R^2$.

Now if $p:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is a Borelfunction then so is composition $p\circ h:E\rightarrow\mathbb R$.

Special case1: $p$ is prescribed by $\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto ax+by$.

Special case2: $p$ is prescribed by $\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto xy$.

In case1 $p\circ h$ can be recognized as $x\mapsto af(x)+bg(x)$

In case2 $p\circ h$ can be recognized as $x\mapsto f(x)g(x)$

So it solves case (i) on an elegant way.

Especially the existence of this easy route makes me reluctant to dive into your efforts.

Comment: what do you mean 'makes you reluctant to dive into my efforts'?

Comment: I believe this is the same as using the theorem in Big Rudin, yes precisely that. This was probably the intended method.

Comment: I am quite lazy and if things can be done easily then I miss motivation to look at the more complex way. Don't take that too serious, though.

Comment: I made an edit to repair $2$ typos.